# Return all back to previous state on mouseleave

Tags: javascript

I have put together this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/YJPV9/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio"></div>
    <div class="portfolio"></div>
    <div class="portfolio"></div>
    <div class="portfolio"></div>
</div>

.portfolio {
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin:20px 20px 0 0;
    background-color:red;

}
#wrapper {
    width:500px;
}
.portfolio:hover {
}

$('.portfolio', '#wrapper').hover(function() {
    $('.portfolio', '#wrapper').not(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: .2
    }, 500);

    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
});
$('.portfolio', '#wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
    ('.portfolio', '#wrapper').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
});
```

I'm looking to return all of the elements back to opacity: 1 when the mouse leaves the wrapper.

Comment: You do know there's a missing `$` in `$('.portfolio', '#wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
    !!!!HERE!!!!!('.portfolio', '#wrapper').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
});`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.portfolio', '#wrapper').hover(function () {
    $('.portfolio', '#wrapper').not(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: .2
    }, 500);
}, function (){
    $('.portfolio', '#wrapper').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YJPV9/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

There was a `$` missing in your Fiddle. Adding that allowed it to work as intended.

Comment: I'm not convinced that adding the `$` actually makes it work as intended.  It certainly makes the code run without error, but I think the effect is ultimately wrong.

Comment: From what I understand, you should be able to see the elements clearly, until you mouseover one of them. Leaving reverts back to original, which is to be able to see them all. It's a choice mechanic, it seems.